# Word Table to CSV file Macro

Tags: vba, csv, ms-word

I'm new to Macros and teaching myself as I go. My goal is to populate a file with data from a Word table using CSV formatting. The table spans over 300 pages with no exact number of rows per page. A user prompt for selecting a file at the beginning has been created. What would be recommended process wise? I know a For loop would be needed for the row count.

```
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim strFile As String

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd

.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Word Files", "*.docx?", 1
.Title = "Choose a Word file"
.AllowMultiSelect = False

.InitialFileName = "C:\VBA Folder"

If .Show = True Then
strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With
```

Intended Output:
Identifer, Artifact Type, Name, Red, Amber, White, Cust, IO_Type, M_680A, M_680_Phase, M_750, Left_Input, Right_Input, Input_Type, Source, Debounce, LOPI, TOPI, ESDI, EFI, BFI, On_gnd, In_air, FDRIO, Auto_test, Frome, Level, VerifiedBy, Status

XXX , Module, X346, , , , , None,6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, S003, , , , , None,6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, ,

XXX , Module, X301, , , , , None,6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X025, , , , , None,6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X511, , , , , None,6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X347, , , , , None,6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X514, , , , , None,6, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, S050, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X021, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X517, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X599, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X022, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X521, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ADD, , ,

XXX , Module, X523, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ADD, , ,

XXX , Module, X019, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, X518, , , , , None,6, ,7, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , SAS, , ,

XXX , Module, M141, , , W, , None,6, ,7, , , ,,0, L, T, , , , , , ,, SAS, ,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At close to its simplest, you can convert a table to CSV format with:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    Set Rng = .Tables(1).Range
    With .Tables(1)
      .ConvertToText Separator:=","
    End With
    Rng.Select
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Simply place the selection point anywhere within the table. The converted range will be selected when the macro finishes.

To save the converted range to a new file, you could use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document
With Selection
  Set DocSrc = .Range.Document
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    Set Rng = .Tables(1).Range
    With .Tables(1)
      .ConvertToText Separator:=","
    End With
    Set DocTgt = Documents.Add
    With DocTgt.Range
      .FormattedText = Rng.FormattedText
      .Characters.Last.Previous.Text = vbNullString
    End With
    DocSrc.Undo
    With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
      .Format = wdFormatText
      .Name = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\MyFile"
      .AddToMru = False
      .Show
    End With
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This will export the converted content to a new file and display the SaveAs dialogue box, with the user's 'Documents' folder selected. You can coose another folder, if you prefer. Then simply substitute your preferred filename, including the .csv extension, for the 'MyFile.txt' offered by the dialogue box.

If you want to exclude particular columns, you could insert code to delete them at 'With .Tables(1)'. For example, to omit the third column:

```
    With .Tables(1)
      .Columns(3).Delete
      .ConvertToText Separator:=","
    End With
```

Comment: My intended result is not formatted quite like this. I forgot to state that at the end of each row, a line break should occur. I have now added the sample output that I am trying to achieve. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: The code I posted already creates a line break (i.e. a paragraph break) at the end of every line, exactly as CSV data should have.

Comment: Would there be a method involving Tables.Cell as an alternate option to the .ConverToText command?

Comment: To what end? Any such macro would be way slower than the .ConverToText method - you did say «spans over 300 pages».

Comment: Understood. For the process of data transfer after, I would proceed to place the contents into a new csv document. For  creation of this document, is there a method that doesn't involve a hard coded approach?                                                          
                                                                                                                                      
 `Dim fld As Object
 Set fld = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Dim myCFile As Object
 Set myCFile = fld.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\c158\Documents\EICAS_Macro\myFile.csv", True)`

Comment: And I apologize for the code in the comment, but I wasn't sure of whether or not it was necessary to edit the question again.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Only other question would be for filtering columns pulled from should I wish to for future cases. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Saw the misunderstanding that could occur from my phrasing. I mean to filter out certain columns in the data collection process. So say if another document that included those columns had excess ones where I didn't need data pulled from, I could keep that out of my end result.

Comment: So delete the unwanted columns before converting to text. Simple as.

Comment: Okay. But placement wise I'm unsure of where I should leave the delete lines as it causes a Run-time error '91'. This occurs on the With DocTgt.Range block.

Comment: Prior to this, the section ran fine (variable was set).

Comment: You do the deletion *before* the csv conversion. The columns don't exist afterwards. See updated answer.